# DDD: modelling aggregate entities' unique global/local id in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, domain-driven-design, aggregate, uniqueidentifier

I have read Eric Evans' Domain Driven Design book and I have been trying to apply some of the concepts.

In his book, Eric talks about aggregates and how aggregate roots should have a unique global id whereas aggregate members should have a unique local id. I have been trying to apply that concept to my database tables and I'm running into some issues.

I have two tables in my PostgreSQL database: facilities and employees where employees can be assigned to a single facility.

In the past, I would lay out the employees table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "employees" (
  "employeeid"  serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "facilityid"  integer NOT NULL,
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY ("facilityid") REFERENCES "facilities" ("facilityid")
);
```

where employeeid is a globally unique id. I would then add code in the backend for access control validation, preventing users of one facility from accessing rows pertaining to other facilities. I have a feeling this might not be the safest way to do it.

What I am now considering is this layout:

```
CREATE TABLE "employees" (
  "employeeid"  integer NOT NULL,
  "facilityid"  integer NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY ("employeeid", "facilityid"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("facilityid") REFERENCES "facilities" ("facilityid")
);
```

where employeeid is unique (locally) for a given facilityid but needs to be paired with a facilityid to be unique globally.

Concretely, this is what I am looking for:

Employee A (employeeid: 1, facilityid: 1)

Employee B (employeeid: 2, facilityid: 1)

Employee C (employeeid: 1, facilityid: 2)

where A, B and C are 3 distinct employees and...

adding an employee D to facility 1 would give him the keys (employeeid : 3, facilityid: 1)

adding an employee E to facility 2 would give him the keys (employeeid : 2, facilityid: 2)

I see two ways of achieving this:

1. I could use triggers or stored procedures to automatically generate new employeeids and store the last ids for every facility in another table for quicker access but I am concerned about concurrency issues and ending up with 2 employees from the same facility with the same id.
2. I could possibly create a new sequence for each facility to manage the employeeids but I fear ending up with thousands of sequences to manage and with procedures to delete those sequences in case a facility is deleted. Is there anything wrong with this? It seems heavy to me.

Which approach should I take? Is there anything I'm missing out on?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to achieve (and what this has to do with DDD). You first describe a One-to-Many relationship as the requirement, but then show data for a Many-to-Many relationship in the 'this is what I am looking for:'.  Are you going to be exposing the Employee entity outside of this bounded-context? Usually, in my experience, the difference between global and local ids is to simply make the global a UUID (or GUID).  Then you know that this id will be unique across bounded-contexts.

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully make it less ambiguous. The relationship I want is One-to-Many and the Employee entity will not be exposed outside of the bounded-context.

I'm mostly looking for the best way to generate those employeeids.

Answer (score 1):

I am inferring from your question that you will be running a single database for all facilities, or at least that if you have a local database as the "master" for each facility that the data will need to be combined in a central database without collisions.

I would make the facilityid the *high order* part of the primary key.  You could probably assign new employee numbers using a simple `SELECT max(employeeid) + 1 ... WHERE facilityid = n` approach, since adding employees to any one facility is presumably not something that happens hundreds of times per second from multiple concurrent sources.  There is some chance that this could generate an occasional serialization failure, but it is my opinion that any database access should be through a framework which recognizes those and automatically retries the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you overstressed the aggregate root concept here. In my understanding of modelling an employee (that depends on your context) an employee is almost always an aggregate root possibly **referenced** by another aggregate root facility.

Both employee and facility almost always have natural keys. For the employee this is typically some employee id (printed on employee identification badges, or at least maintained in the human resources software system) and facilities have this natural keys too almost always containing some location part and some number like "*MUC-1*" for facility 1 located in munich. But that all depends on your context. In case employee and facility have this natural keys your database model should be quite clear.